# How to embed a PDF file into an existing one with iText 5

Tags: java, itext

I have a main PDF with 25 pages and my goal is to insert another PDF with 5 pages starting at page number 10 in the main PDF. At the end I will have a 30 page PDF document.

```
try {
            PdfReader mainFileReader= new PdfReader(mainFile);
            PdfReader fileToCopyReader = new PdfReader(fileToCopy);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(mainFileReader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));

             int n = fileToCopyReader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(fileToCopyReader, i);
                **//how to insert the above page to the stamper?**
                stamper.insertPage(10+(i-1),
                        fileToCopyReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i));
            }           
            stamper.close();
            reader.close();
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The above code is inserting blank pages but how to insert pages from other PDF instead of blank pages? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [Concatenate.java](https://github.com/itext/i5js-book/blob/develop/src/part2/chapter06/Concatenate.java) from the itext 5 samples [book](https://github.com/itext/i5js-book)

Comment: Don't create a completely unconnected new `PdfWriter` instance. Instead try using `stamper.getWriter()`.

Comment: @j_b: thank u. quick question.. Isn't the code sample adding the documents one after the other? Is there a way to insert the second document at a specific page number and add remaining pages of first document at last.

Comment: @mkl: Will do. Thank u

Comment: @gvg. Sure, you will need to loop through the 1st pdf adding pages to the output pdf up to the page where you want to start adding the 2nd pdf to the output pdf.  Then add all the pages from the 2nd pdf to the output pdf.  Finally finish adding the remaining pages from the 1st pdf to the output pdf.

Comment: @j_b: That makes sense. Thanks!